# var_dump a php Class object reveals database username and password

Tags: php, database, class, object, var-dump

I am a bit worried when I incidentally `var_dump()` the object of a child class, the result showed all my sql elements and variable values including database username,password and DBname. Is there a security issue with it. If yes how do I shield it? Would be thankful if someone show me a light on it.

```
$ClassObject=new MyChildClass();
var_dump($ClassObject);
```

A sample result is as follows:-

> object(MyChildClass)#1 (17) { ["database":protected]=> object(Crud)#2
>   (13) { ["rows"]=> string(12) "column_name" ["vals"]=> NULL ["query"]=>
>   NULL ["table"]=> string(8) "users" ["DB_TYPE":"Database":private]=>
>   string(5) "mysql" ["host":"Database":private]=> string(9) "localhost"
>   ["user":"Database":private]=> string(4) "root"
>   ["pass":"Database":private]=> string(7) "mypass"
>   ["db":"Database":private]=> string(13) "mydbname"
>   ["conn":"Database":private]=> object(PDO)#3 (0) { }
>   ["error":"Database":private]=> NULL ["result"]=> NULL
>   ["stmt":"Database":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) {
>   ["queryString"]=> string(51) "SELECT column_name FROM ms_users WHERE
>   userid=:uid" } } ["loguserid":"Users":private]=> string(1) "4"
>   ["rows"]=> array(0) { } ["vals"]=> NULL ["query"]=> NULL ["table"]=>
>   string(16) "MyTable_name" ["DB_TYPE":"Database":private]=> string(5)
>   "mysql" ["host":"Database":private]=> string(9) "localhost"
>   ["user":"Database":private]=> string(4) "root"
>   ["pass":"Database":private]=> string(7) "MyPass"
>   ["db":"Database":private]=> string(13) "mydbname"
>   ["conn":"Database":private]=> NULL ["error":"Database":private]=> NULL
>   ["result"]=> NULL ["stmt":"Database":private]=> NULL ["join"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["where"]=> string(35) "user_id=:id1 AND
>   column_name=:id2" }

Answer (score 4):

The magic method [__debugInfo](http://php.net/__debugInfo) does just that. In your class, add the following code:

```
public function __debugInfo()
{
    $properties = get_object_vars($this);
    unset($properties['host']);
    unset($properties['user']);
    unset($properties['pass']);

    return $properties;
}
```

**How it works**: the first line retrieves the full list of properties in the current instance. Then, with `unset`, we remove all the properties we don't want displayed by `var_dump`.
Modify the code to remove from `$properties` all the properties you want to hide.

In this first example, all properties except 3 will be displayed when using `var_dump` on this object.

Or use a safer way: create an empty array and populate it only with the properties you want displayed:

```
public function __debugInfo()
{
    $properties = [];
    $properties[] = 'table';
    $properties[] = 'queryString';

    return $properties;
}
```

In this second example, only 2 properties will be displayed when using `var_dump` on this object.

By adding this method to all your classes, you can control exactly what gets displayed when using `var_dump`.

Documentation: [__debugInfo](http://php.net/__debugInfo)

Comment: Thanks ! Jocelyn I got it.